# Вставить JS событие, чтобы оно срабатывало

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно вставить JS событие, а именно:

```
onclick="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;
```

На кнопку:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 wrap-area">
<div class="question_btn text-center"><button class="wpb_none btn btn-primary  btn-lg btn-large js-modal-form" data-btn="Оформить заявку на подключение" data-frm="name,tel" data-mtitle="Заполните формы ниже и мы свяжемся с вами в течении 10 минут" data-success="Мы перезвоним Вам в ближайшее время." data-toggle="modal" data-tomail="Заявка на подключение" type="submit"</button></div>
</div>
```

В какое место его нужно поместить, чтобы при нажатии, событие активировалось?

Answer (score 2):

Крайне советую почитать: [Reach Goal](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/objects/reachgoal.xml)

По коду:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 wrap-area">
  <div class="question_btn text-center">
    <button class="wpb_none btn btn-primary  btn-lg btn-large js-modal-form" data-btn="Оформить заявку на подключение" data-frm="name,tel" data-mtitle="Заполните формы ниже и мы свяжемся с вами в течении 10 минут" data-success="Мы перезвоним Вам в ближайшее время."
      data-toggle="modal" data-tomail="Заявка на подключение" onclick="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;" type="submit"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

где XXXXXX меняете на свой идентификатор в Яндекс Метрике.